# Java Compiler Issue: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, date, symbols

I am trying to format a String into a date but getting java compiler error:

The fragment of code is:

```
String value = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
//String dateInString = value;
SimpleDateFormat parse = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
if (isFirst){
   Date date = parse.parse(value);
   //Then I'll just put the date variable into a cell in the html table.
```

The error I am getting:

**cannot find symbol**

```
 [javac] symbol  : constructor SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)
     [javac] location: class com.lb.base.util.extra.SimpleDateFormat
     [javac]                             SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
     [javac]                                                          ^
```

I get this for both times I am declaring new SimpleDateFormat. I have checked that import is not the issue. Quite confused to what it is then..why am I getting this 'cannot find symbol' error?

Comment: "*I have checked that import is not the issue*" => are you sure? => `location: class com.lb.base.util.extra.SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: You're importing the wrong SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 3):

Thanks folks, I fixed it by commenting out the first import
`com.lb.base.util.extra.SimpleDateFormat`

and adding

`import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

below it. Guess we can't let the two imports happen at the same time.

Comment: Watch out if you're using an IDE's auto-completion feature. Sometimes you can get the same class of other packages than what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Your import seems to be off.  You want to use java's SimpleDataFormat and not com.lb.base.util.extra whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're trying to import `com.lb.base.util.extra.SimpleDateFormat`

Did you mean to import the java.text one? If yes try changing to below:

`import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

Or change the line you call the constructor:

`java.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: using new.java.text.SimpleDateFormat gives error 'incompatible types'

Comment: found   : java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    [javac] required: com.lb.base.util.extra.SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 0):

Something in your code, or the code your using, is very oddly expecting a non-standard version of a very standard class. You should search the source-code for this import statement:

```
import  com.lb.base.util.extra.SimpleDateFormat;
```

or for a class/java file *named* SimpleDateFormat.java

This is pretty difficult to diagnose without having direct access to your computer, but it seems like you are trying to use two classes with exactly the same name.

One other thought: Instead of this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

try explicit package names to bypass import statements:

```
xbn.text.SimpleDateFormat formatter = new xbn.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I am assuming here that you *want* to use the standard Java versions.

Here is a link with some information that may be instructive:

https://www.google.com/search?q=is+already+defined+in+a+single-type+import+%5Bjavac%5D+import

Comment: I see. But when I tried, I got this error..
 [javac] /path to filename.java:6: com.lb.base.util.extra.SimpleDateFormat is already defined in a single-type import
    [javac] import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    [javac] ^

Comment: Yes I did that. but then I get the cannot find symbol error again. 
 [javac] symbol  : constructor SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,java.util.Locale)
    [javac] location: class com.lb.base.util.extra.SimpleDateFormat
    [javac]                             SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: Hopefully the latest update to my answer will help you. It is an interesting problem.